# How to fix wrong layout for AZERTY keyboards

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have a Sony VAIO SVS1311F3EW with a French Keyboard (AZERTY). It is a great laptop and worked perfectly fine until i took an Ubuntu update sometime in 2015. My keyboard was messed up; some keys are not working anymore.

My laptop brand is not listed by the command sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration. Changing input sources did not help either. I was hoping that this issue will get fixed with future Ubuntu releases but it never was.

Can you give me an update regarding keyboard layout issues, specially for AZERTY keyboards?

The issue started four years ago and i have been using an USB keyboard since then because that problem was never solved.

Keys not working:

- Square Symbol " ² ". Before the first key " 1 & "
- " 6_ | "
- " ° ) ] "
- " Z "
- " D "
- " F "
- " H "
- " J "
- " L "
- " % ù "
- " > < "
- " Shift R "
- " fn "
- " Right "
- " Delete "
- " Print "
- " F2 "
- " F4 "
- " F6 "
- " F9 "
- " F11 "

As you can see, almost all the keys in my keyboard are not working. That's irritating.

Thank you.

[image]

Soni model is not listed in the keyboard config

[image]

Comment: Updated my description

Comment: 1. `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

`XKBLAYOUT=us,ara,fr
BACKSPACE=guess
XKBVARIANT=,,azerty`

2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

`[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ara'), ('xkb', 'fr+azerty')]`

Comment: I did but the result is the same. 
Please note that i am currently typing comments with a QWERTY USB keyboard. I have to keep English input turned ON.

Comment: Picture uploaded

Comment: Ubuntu  18.04.e LTS. Gnome 3.28.2.

I created three input sources from the settings, as you can see in the commands output. It created a drop down list of layouts to help me switch from QWERTY to AZERTY

Just FYI - Having multiple layouts installed did not cause the issue. The problem started right after taking an Ubuntu update.

Comment: I tried all the french layouts available from the settings but without any success. I also tried different keyboard models listed by the command  `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.
 
Soni keyboard model needs to be programmed and added to the list of keyboard configuration. That will definitely solve my problem

Comment: I see that the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/sony` exists. Maybe this should be reported as an [upstream issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/issues).

Comment: Thank you. Can you please escalate that issue?

Comment: Well, I meant to suggest that you file a new issue. Given our conversation, I suppose it should focus on Sony devices rather than a particular keyboard layout.